# Bingbot trying to access lower case urls when i am using a mixture of uppercase and lowercase

Tags: url, 301-redirect, local-seo

I have a website (dynamic real estate website) that has been up for nearly a year, all of a sudden Bingbots are trying to access completely lower case versions of the main pages resulting in 404 errors.

The base url is lowercase but subsequent pages are a mixture.

```
https://example.com/Houses-for-sale-in-Suburb-STATE-3345.php
```

I have read up on rel canonical and 301 redirects and since have learned that using uppercase is not a good idea - although I decided to use them because states in my country are expressed in UPPERCASE

I am not sure how to handle this, if I convert all of the uppercase URLs to lower case then the bots will still try to access the uppercase versions.

Comment: What web server? There may be options to set depending upon the web server. Cheers!!

Comment: Just as a point of reference, I realize this it too late for the OP, however, never, never, never, use upper case or mixed case URLs unless you absolutely have no choice. Even then, do not do it! ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: Pretty sure it is a Centos server on shared host, accessed via CPanel without root privileges.

Comment: I am assuming Apache. It may be a bit of work, however, this may help and make your site more usable overall: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Comment: Just tried it in .htaccess see @Grizzly [link](https://http://serverfault.com/questions/177647/convert-and-redirect-url-in-uppercase-to-lowercase-using-htaccess) however I don't have access to httpd.conf, so of course got a 500 Server error

Comment: Oh. I would have to think about this. Perhaps symlinks of lowercase URIs pointing to your mixed case URIs. Not sure how to do that with cPanel, but I am sure you can. You should be able to get to your conf file via cPanel - right? Unless you are on shared hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Ostermiller gave me the answer to proceed with testing and to implement the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine

Redirect 301 /houses-for-sale-in-suburb-state-3345.php http://example.com/Houses-for-sale-in-Suburb-STATE-3345.php
```

I wrote a redirect for every single page that had CAPS in the URL, except for the dynamically created URL's, which are driven by RewriteRules in the .htaccess & put the Redirects above the RewriteRules

Answer (score 0):

When I worked for TripAdvisor, we saw this problem all the time.  TripAdvisor has mixed case URLs like:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60763-New_York_City_New_York-Hotels.html
```

Many crawlers including BingBot would try to lower case the entire URL before fetching it.   To fix the issue we made sure that all lowercase URLs would redirect to the mixed case version.  So the following gives a 301 redirect:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/hotels-g60763-new_york_city_new_york-hotels.html
```

We used the ID in the URL to figure out the correct URL and redirect.   It looks like you have a numeric id in your URL that you could use as well.

Because of this experience, I recommend that the canonical version of URLs always be all lowercase.   I don't recommend using mixed case URLs because there are so many badly programmed crawlers.

StackExchange does something similar.   If you request a butchered URL with the id still intact, you will get a redirect to the correct thing.   You can test this by fetching the following URL for this question:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100613/BINGBOT-IS-DUMB
```

I also recommend that numeric ids go near the front of the URL because of truncation issues.    You can correct for

```
/Hotels-g60763-New_Yor...
```

but not as easily for:

```
/Houses-for-sale-in-Su...
```